# Detection error on HDD0 for Lenovo L480

Tags: laptop, ssd, lenovo-laptop, hardware-detection

I had an issue with Lenovo Laptop about two weeks ago. It is used to give me a complete blue screen once/twice a day before complete blackout for HDD0 detection error. Generally, the issue is related to SSD or bad connection and may need to open the laptop to resolve the issue. As this is an office provided laptop, I am not authorized to open it and check the issue. Is there any other way/solution to resolve this problem?
Is there any way to try to check the issue using the BIOS key?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should bring the laptop to the IT department of your company and let them fix this issue. (or call them to ask how to handle this)

Answer (score 0):

Yes true that is the first step to do, but due to the COVID19 condition, this will not work.
And now, I have resolved the issue by running all diagnostic tests more than 12+hours for Lenovo and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has not been resolved completely, it gave me a blue screen minimum twice a day. but by running Lenovo's quick diagnostic test, I have managed to work.